# Confusion regarding solution manual's entry to Question 3b Chapter 8 of Spivak's Calculus

Tags: real-analysis

Question 3b from Chapter 8 of Spivak's Calculus reads as:

> The proof of the Theorem 7-1 depended upon considering $A = \{x: a \leq x \leq b \text{ and } f \text{ is negative on } [a,x]\}$. Give another proof of Theorem 7-1, which depends upon consideration of $B=\{x : a \leq x \leq b \text{ and } f(x) \lt 0 \}$. Which point $x$ in $[a,b]$ with $f(x)=0$ will this proof locate? Give an example where the sets $A$ and $B$ are not the same.

The proof of Theorem 7-1 is sort of long, so I would prefer if I did not have to transcribe it here (I can, if necessary), but the theorem is as follows:

> If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f(a) \lt 0 \lt f(b)$, then there is some number $x$ in $[a,b]$ such that $f(x)=0$.

The solution manual offers an answer to question 3b asserting that for $\alpha=\sup(B)$, $f(\alpha)=0$. While I agree with this statement, Spivak concludes with:

> This $\alpha$  is the greatest $x$ in $[a,b]$ with $f(x)=0$.

**I disagree with this statement.**

He then provides the following picture, which compares how set $A$ can potentially differ from set $B$:

[image: picture1]

It is certainly true for the above picture that "$\alpha$  is the greatest $x$ in $[a,b]$ with $f(x)=0$". However, this does not strike me as being generally true. For example, consider the following graph of a function $g$, which is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $g(a) \lt 0 \lt g(b)$:

[image: pic2]

I just want a sanity check that this is a typo (or an explanation as to how I am misunderstanding the claim).

Comment: Good catch, and a nice, clear counterexample image. 

Perhaps they meant to instead define the set as 
$$B = \{x: a \leq x \leq b \text { and } f(x) \leq 0\}$$ 

Points for your diligence!